# Word that is nearly but not quite, hypochondriac or malingerer or Munchausen sufferer?

Tags: single-word-requests

**Background**

I made a doctor appointment for a minor health worry. The usual practitioner was on leave so I saw a locum. The new doctor was quite dismissive and may have written something disparaging in the medical notes. I was worried my regular doctor might be influenced by this.

**Problem**

I wanted to say to my GP.

I enquired about problem X while you were away and your stand-in was quite dismissive. I wouldn't like you to think I am a _______ "

**Excluded answers**

hypochondriac - This was a real ailment *and the locum admitted it* but dismissed it as unimportant and seemed to think I was wasting his time. In fact it turned out that my own GP commended me for mentioning it as treatment was needed.

malingerer - I was not trying to shirk my work or responsibilities. I wanted treatment so I could *carry on* with my daily activities.

Munchausen sufferer - This stems from a desire to interact with doctors as much as possible. That doesn't describe me at all. I prefer to keep away from doctors and hospitals.

**Question**

So what is the term? Can you offer me a single word or, failing that, a concise phrase.

Comment: I'd actually say hypochondriac fits quite well; you actually had the ailment, so you _wouldn't_ want the doctor to think you were a hypochondriac.

Comment: I think *shirker*,  or other synonyms, could fit in your sentence if you are worried that your doctor may think you are looking for  excuses to stay at home from work

Comment: I wouldn't want you to think I am plagued by hypochondria.

Comment: Any of your suggestions would actually work, because you wouldn't want the doctor to think that of you: none of those epithets applies, and you would like to draw the doctor's attention to the fact that he shouldn't be using them of you.

Comment: Okay - I see that several of you have objected to my exclusions. That tells me I need to improve the wording of my question. I don't have time right now but I will come back and try to formulate it better. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I would advise rephrasing this as "I enquired about problem X while you were away and your stand-in was quite dismissive. I would like you to note that problem x had greater impact than your colleague assessed and that it was of greater significance, as demonstrated by the need for subsequent treatment." This avoids the problem of using a word which, if recorded, doesn't strongly place on record your precise feelings and the reasons for them, which appears to be the goal of your discussion with the doctor.

Comment: I wouldn’t worry about what your doctor thinks of you. You’ve got a long history with him and he already has a well-formed opinion of you.  Doctor’s are pretty smart.  it sounds like the person who should be worrying is your doctor- who evidently has an incompetent  for a stand-in.  (If it’s true that you really did require subsequent treatment)  On  the other hand it’s also possible that your doctor knows you’re a hypochondriac and knows that if he just gives you something for a treatment, that will keep everyone happy.

Comment: If this is a real situation, ask to view your medical records, which you are fully entitled to do. I wouldn't say anything like 'I wouldn't want you to think I'm a....' any of the things you suggest, or even 'neurotic'.That implies you think you might be yourself, and are anxious that someone else might do too. The fact you're anxious about what the locum has said might indicate an overly high level of anxiety anyway.... I'd say as little as possible other than telling him you weren't impressed with the locum's manner.

Comment: **"I wouldn't want you to get the wrong idea/impression"**, leaves it open-ended, it can mean anything or nothing in particular. The onus is on the listener to supply his/her POV. But I would prefer telling my doctor that I felt uncomfortable and ill at ease with the locum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"I wouldn't like you to think I am a **valetudinarian**"

[Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/valetudinarian):

> A person who is *unduly* anxious about their health.

Comment: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/valetudinarian For the link and a more assertive alternative definition : see under Collins English  Dictionary

Comment: Wow! - Excellent. I've  read or heard the word somewhere before but had no idea what it meant. I would never have come up with that in a million years. *(well maybe a million)*

Comment: My pleasure, I don't know why I remember it but my first girlfriend years and years ago would talk about her father as one, she liked the word. I think this is the first time I've ever had a meaningful purpose to bring it up, I had to attempt a spelling and let Google auto correct it.